# soundex implementation

Tags: algorithm, strings, haskell

The soundex algorithm maps several spellings of a name to a 4 character term. (hopefully mapping all different transcriptions to the same term) The steps as described in *[Introduction to information retrieval](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/pdf/03dict.pdf)* are:

- Keep first Letter for the rest:
- Change any of 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U', 'H', 'W', 'Y' to zero
- Change all other characters to 1-6, see below
- remove consecutive doubles
- remove all zeros, right pad with 0s, keep first 3

I implemented a working solution, but can it be implemented more readable?

```
import Data.Char

soundex :: String -> String
soundex []      = []
soundex (n:ame) = result
  where 
    compr  = map (compress . toUpper) ame
    noDoub = remDoubles compr
    noZero = filter (/='0') noDoub
    result = n: take 3 (noZero++"000")

remDoubles :: String -> String
remDoubles []       = []
remDoubles (a:[])   = [a]
remDoubles (a:b:bs) | a==b      = remDoubles   (b:bs)
                    | otherwise = a:remDoubles (b:bs)

compress :: Char -> Char
compress char | char `elem` "AEIOUHWY" = '0'
              | char `elem` "BFPV"     = '1'
              | char `elem` "CGJKQSXZ" = '2'
              | char `elem` "DT"       = '3'
              | char `elem` "L"        = '4'
              | char `elem` "MN"       = '5'
              | char `elem` "R"        = '6'
              | otherwise              = char
```

Answer (score 4):

### Correctness

The algorithm is actually quite tricky to implement correctly.  Your algorithm gives the wrong results for some examples in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex):

$$\begin{array}{l|l|l}
\textrm{Name} & \textrm{Correct Soundex} & \textrm{Your result} \\
\hline
\textrm{Ashcroft} & \textrm{A261} & \textrm{A226} \\
\textrm{Pfister} & \textrm{P236} & \textrm{P123} \\
\end{array}$$

Specifically, note the following rule:

> Two letters with the same number separated by 'h' or 'w' are coded as a single number, whereas such letters separated by a vowel are coded twice. This rule also applies to the first letter.

As a consequence, the code must…

- … treat "H" and "W" differently from the vowels, so `` char `elem` "AEIOUHWY" = '0' `` is wrong.  I recommend using `'0'` to temporarily indicate the presence of a vowel, and dropping `'H'` and `'W'` unless it is in the initial position.
- … lookup the digit for the first character too, to see if the next nonzero digit should be discarded.  Therefore, `compr  = map (compress . toUpper) ame` is wrong.

### Style

`ame` and `noDoub` are pretty weird variable names.  For a clear and idiomatic function definition, I suggest

```
soundex name@(n:ns) = n : take 3 (noZero ++ "000")
  where
    …
```

Note that `result` should probably be eliminated.

`remDoubles` could be simplified to `map head . group`, using the `group` function from `Data.List`.  I would rename `remDoubles` to `dedup`.

`compress` is oddly named, as it maps one `Char` to exactly one `Char`.

I prefer imports to be more explicit about what functions are imported.

### Suggested solution

```
import Data.Char (toUpper)
import Data.List (group)

soundex :: String -> String
soundex []   = []
soundex name = (toUpper $ head name) : nnn
  where
    dedup = map head . group
    nnn = take 3 $ (++ "000") $ filter (/= '0') $ tail $ dedup $ digitize name

digitize :: String -> String
digitize name = d : filter (/= '-') ds
  where
    digitFor c
      | c `elem` "AEIOUY"   = '0'
      | c `elem` "BFPV"     = '1'
      | c `elem` "CGJKQSXZ" = '2'
      | c `elem` "DT"       = '3'
      | c `elem` "L"        = '4'
      | c `elem` "MN"       = '5'
      | c `elem` "R"        = '6'
      | otherwise           = '-'   -- 'H', 'W', and punctuation
    (d:ds) = map (digitFor . toUpper) name
```

Note that the order of the chain of functions used to define `nnn` is critical.  Yours was closer to…

> ```
> nnn = take 3 $ (++ "000") $ filter (/= '0') $ dedup $ digitize $ tail name
> ```

… which explains the "Pfister" bug.

To address the "Ashcroft" bug, I've rewritten `compress` as `digitize`, which can return a shorter string that drops output corresponding to a non-initial `'H'` and `'W'`.

Comment: I added a link to the textbook I'm using. The author admits, hidden in "References", to using his own version.

Comment: I can't change only 2 chars, so I comment: I strongly believe it has to be `dedup = map head $ group`

Comment: No, it is written as intended. It's the point-free style of `dedup str  = map head $ group str`.

Comment: Oh, I see. I tried `map head . group "Missisippi"` in ghci, but I have to try `(map head . group) "Missisippi"` of course.

Comment: I would replace digitize by http://lpaste.net/940008100159553536 , though note that your d might be '-', which isn't possible for me.

Comment: @Gurkenglas Nice. I suggest that you post that as an answer reviewing the `compress` function.